# Update html JTextPane by div id?

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane, htmleditorkit

I am using a `JTextPane` to print out chat messages, implementation:

```
private HTMLEditorKit kit;
private HTMLDocument doc;
ta = new JTextPane();
ta.setEditable(false);
ta.setContentType("text/html");
sbrText = new JScrollPane(ta);
sbrText.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);     
sbrText.setBorder(null);
doc = (HTMLDocument)ta.getDocument();
kit = (HTMLEditorKit)ta.getEditorKit();
```

The messages are being inserted like this:

```
try {
    kit.insertHTML(doc, doc.getLength(), "<div style=\"padding-top:10px; 
          padding-bottom:10px;\" id=\"X\">" + "<div>" + from + " at 
          " + tid + ":</div>" + "<div style=\"padding-top:4px;" + 
          align + "\">" + msg + "</div>" + "</div>", 0, 0, null);
} catch (BadLocationException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Each message (div) gets a unique ID, i want to select a certain ID and update the contents of that html insert.

Is this possible?

Comment: If you would like to avoid traversing the whole DOM, perhaps my answer may be of help.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible. You can get the document from the `JTextPane` and use `getDefaultRootElement()` to get root of the DOM. Then go through all the childrent and children of children Elements. For each of them use `getAttributes()` and check whether there is ID attribute. Then check the attribute value.

When you achieve `Element` with specified ID use `HTMLDocument`'s method

```
public void setOuterHTML(Element elem, String htmlText)
```

Comment: Not really sure i understand how to write that could u do an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

- **Select a certain ID**

Since each DIV has a unique ID, you can use the [`getElement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#getElement%28java.lang.String%29) method from the [`HTMLDocument`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html) class to fetch exactly the DIV in question. Thus, you don't need to traverse the whole DOM scanning for elements with an ID attribute and comparing IDs.

- **Update the contents of that html insert**

Although [`setOuterHTML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#setOuterHTML%28javax.swing.text.Element,%20java.lang.String%29) allows you to replace the contents of a given element, it also replaces the element itself. What you need instead is [`setInnerHTML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html#setInnerHTML%28javax.swing.text.Element,%20java.lang.String%29) which, as it name suggests, leaves the containing tags untouched.

All in all, the code for what you are trying to do would go along the following lines:

```
public void replaceContents (String sID, String sContents) {
        try {
            doc.setInnerHTML (doc.getElement (sID), sContents);
        } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }       
    }
```

Hope that helps!